Handling multiple render targets of differing sizes in Metal
I would like to use a fragment shader with multiple render targets to output YCbCr data from RGB input, where the Y data is written to one texture and the CbCr to another, smaller texture (due to chroma subsampling). A comment on this answer seems to suggest that this is possible (and even a preferred method), but I can't seem to figure out how.
I know I can render to multiple targets by returning a struct from the fragment and adding multiple color attachments when setting up the render pipeline (see snippets below). When I do this, however, the final rendered area seems to correspond only to the smaller texture, meaning that the Y texture can't be fully populated by the fragment. Even if the rendered area corresponded to the larger texture, I don't quite understand how the two outputs from the fragment would be resolved correctly into each texture given that the render targets are of different sizes. What am I missing? Do I have to do something special in the rasterization stage?
struct Output {
    float y [[ color(0) ]]; 
    float2 cbCr [[ color(1) ]]; 
};

fragment Output example(texture2d<float, access::read> rgbInput [[ texture(0) ]], ...)
{
     Output out; 
     // Populate data...
     return out;     
}

let descriptor = MTLRenderPassDescriptor()
descriptor.colorAttachments[0].texture = yTexture // full-size texture
descriptor.colorAttachments[1].texture = cbCrTexture // smaller texture
... // Set up the rest of the render pass as usual


You cannot have render targets of different sizes bound to the same render pass. It's just not possible to do with MTLRenderCommandEncoder. It requires all render targets to be the same size. Think about it in terms of dispatching a fragment shader. If you have a 1000x1000 render target and a 500x500 render target, how would you run a fragment shader? In a grid of 1000x1000? But then what do you do to chose one out of four output values for render target 2. 500x500? But then you are just quadrupling the same output into the 1000x1000 render target.

It is possible to do with MTLRenderCommandEncoder, but as mentioned the fragment will only run over the area defined by the smaller target. I understand that the outputs wouldn't really make sense (hence "I don't quite understand how the two outputs from the fragment would be resolved correctly into each texture given that the render targets are of different sizes"), but that brings me back to the original question – any insights as to what the linked comment might have been talking about?

For easier reference, the comment I'm referring to was upvoted more than once and said: "multiple render targets is very useful for RGB to YCbCr conversion when CbCr texture has resolution two time less in comparison to Y". I could see using multiple targets to output Y and CbCr textures of the same size, then another pass to downsample the CbCr texture. Maybe that's what they were referring to? How would you do it?

Two render passes or compute.
